# How to properly take screen shots in Xamarin iOS simulator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin.ios

I am currently taking screen shots for my application using iOS simulator. The issue I am coming across is that they are being being taking with borders and causing it to be rejected.

[image]

I have another approved application with screen shots and it doesn't have rounded borders.

[image]

I am using this button to take screen shots

[image]

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run the iOS simulator in the `Mac` and then take the screenshot. I did a test and the screenshot in the mac does not has the rounded borders.

Another way is you can use some tools to edit those screenshots to achieve what you want:).